# Is there a long exact cofiber sequence for a homotopy pushout?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $f:Z \to X$, $g: Z \to Y$ and let $M(f,g)$ be the corresponding mapping cylinder. Does the homotopy pushout diagram induce a long cofiber sequence?
If so what does it look like?

Comment: [Very related (if not duplicate, I'm not sure what you want exactly: a LES in homology? Or on the level of spaces?)](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/645972/10014)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I'm interested in whether there's a long cofiber sequence in the sense that taking $Hom(-,W)$ of it in the homotopy category would produce a long exact sequence of pointed sets and groups.

Comment: As far as I understand there are *two* cofiber sequences, and they are in some sort of "long exact braid". I'll see tomorrow if I can write something (but in the meantime maybe someone will already have).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Thanks, I'll be patient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is the following: if $W$ is an Eilenberg-MacLane space, or more generally an infinite loop space, then $[-, W]$ produces from this homotopy pushout diagram a homotopy pullback diagram of infinite loop spaces, and then this thing produces a long fiber sequence and hence a long exact sequence in cohomology. (Well, part of it: to get the rest you need to extend this long fiber sequence to a long cofiber sequence in the other direction, or equivalently to repeatedly deloop $W$.)

Comment: That's great only I'm not familiar with the long fiber sequence of a homotopy pullbak either...

Comment: @Saal: the point is that once you're in the setting of infinite loop spaces you can now subtract maps, so you can replace computing the homotopy pullback of two maps $f : A \to C, g : B \to C$ with computing the homotopy fiber of $f - g : A \oplus B \to C$ (same as with abelian groups).

Comment: Thanks, I definitely need to read more about this stuff. It really helps to have someone pointing in the right direction.