# A question on cell attachments.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

Let $n \geq 2$ and let $\alpha: S^{n-1} \to S^{n-1}$ be a continuous map of degree $a$, meaning that the homomorphism induced on the $n$-th homology is multiplication by $a$. Let $S^{n-1} \cup_{\alpha} D^n$ be the space obtained by attaching an $n$-dimensional cell to $S^{n-1}$ along $\alpha$. Compute $H_k( S^{n-1} \cup_{\alpha} D^n)$ for all $k$.

The homology groups I am talking about here is the ones of the complex $S_{\ast}(X)$ for a topological space $X$, more precisely  $S_{\ast}(X)$ is the complex $... \to S_n(X) \to ... \to S_2(X) \to S_1(X) \to S_0(X)$ where $S_k(X)$ is the free abelian group generated by all singular simplexes of dimension $k$, i.e all continuous maps $\sigma: \Delta^k \to X$. Kind of feel lost on this exercise, and it is supposed to be an easy one...

Comment: I think Arthur's answer is good, but if you would like to understand the answer at the level of the chain complexes, I think it would be easier to use CW homology than singular (they are isomorphic). Is that an option?

Comment: @ziggurism The section does not really include anything on CW homology, it comes in a couple of chapters, maybe I should save the exercise for later, I will try to solve it with Arthurs answer.

Comment: @ziggurism Does he mean that for degree $n-2$ or lower the homology remains same as for $S^{n-1}$, for $n-1$ it is $\mathbb{Z}_a$ and for $k \geq n$ it is $0$?

Comment: yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @ziggurism For $k \not= n$, $k \not= n-1$ I totally see that the homology group is $\mathbb{Z}$ for $k=0$ and $0$ otherwise. But I don't see the cases $k=n-1$ and $k=n$. For instance how do we get $\mathbb{Z}_a$ for $H_{n-1}$?

Comment: perhaps you would like to try Mayer-Vietoris?

Comment: @ziggurism I did, just failed, but I will try again. What do you suggest more precisely?

Comment: Ok I have added an answer explaining how to use Mayer-Vietoris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Mayer-Vietoris theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayer%E2%80%93Vietoris_sequence) says we have a long exact sequence

$$
0\to H_n(S^{n-1} \cup_{\alpha} D^n)\overset{\partial}\to H_{n-1}(S^{n-1} \cap D^n)\overset{i_1\oplus i_2}\to H_{n-1}(S^{n-1})\oplus H_{n-1}(D^n)\overset{p_1-p_2}\to H_{n-1}(S^{n-1} \cup_{\alpha} D^n)\to0
$$
where $i_1,i_2,p_1,p_2$ are the subspace inclusion maps, respectively, $S^{n-1}\cap D^n\hookrightarrow S^{n-1},S^{n-1}\cap D^n\hookrightarrow D^n,S^{n-1}\hookrightarrow S^{n-1} \cup_{\alpha} D^n,$ and $D^n\hookrightarrow S^{n-1} \cup_{\alpha} D^n.$ Then from the induced maps in homology are formed $i_1\oplus i_2$ and $p_1-p_2.$

And we have $S^{n-1}\cap D^n\simeq S^{n-1},$ $H_{n-1}(D^n)\cong0,$ $i_2=0=p_2,$ and $i_1=\alpha$ is the degree $a$ map. And of course $H_{n-1}(S^{n-1})\cong\mathbb{Z}.$

Since $\alpha$ is injective, we have $H_n(S^{n-1} \cup_{\alpha} D^n)\cong 0.$

Now our sequence is $$0\to \mathbb{Z}\overset{a}\to\mathbb{Z}\to H_{n-1}(S^{n-1} \cup_{\alpha} D^n)\to 0,$$ from which it follows $H_{n-1}(S^{n-1} \cup_{\alpha} D^n)=\mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z}.$

The part which I think is a little confusing is, how can $i_1$ be the non-injective degree $a$ map, when it is supposed to be the subspace inclusion 
$S^{n-1}\cap D^n\cong S^{n-1}\hookrightarrow S^{n-1}$? Surely this inclusion is just the identity map?

Well, no. Remember that Mayer-Vietoris requires that we use open sets $A$, $B$ that cover the total space $X=S^{n-1} \cup_{\alpha} D^n$. $S^{n-1}$ and $D^n$ do not do this, they are closed sets, $S^{n-1}$ contains no neighborhoods of $X$. So we must fatten up our sphere, and retract our disk a bit. Something like $A=S^{n-1}\times[0,\frac{2}{3})$ and $B=S^{n-1}\times(\frac{1}{3},1]/S^{n-1}\times \{1\}$ (so a cone on $S^{n-1}$ that doesn't go "all the way out", so to speak). And although they are homotopy equivalent to $S^{n-1}$ and $D^n$, respectively, it is these subspaces $A$ and $B$ which should have appeared in the MV sequence above, and which determine the maps.

Then we see the intersection $A\cap B\hookrightarrow A$ does map into the fat boundary via the degree $a$ attaching map.

See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/646215/16490).

Comment: @user502427 I will reiterate that this space is a very simple CW space, with only a few cells. Mayer-Vietoris with singular homology is ok, but CW homology is much easier! Let me know if you want me to post the answer in that form as well.

Comment: Whether you use MV, or the relative homology exact sequence, or cellular homology, that's the way to go to actually calculate homology groups of relatively simple spaces. Singular homology is great for general proofs, but it's difficult to use in concrete calculations, since the groups you work in are uncountably generated rather than (usually) finitely generated.

Comment: Thank you for this very explaining answer. However I suspect you mixed up some notations, for instance $p_1-p_1$, I will accept your answer as soon as this is edited. Thank you!

Comment: @user502427 sorry, that should say $p_1-p_2.$