# Generalization of wedge sum?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm currently trying to understand the various ways in which topological spaces can be glued together.

If we take two circles and join them together at a single point, we get $F = S^1 \vee S^1$. Calculating the homology groups using $\Delta$-complexes yields $H_1^\Delta(F) = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ and $H_0^\Delta(F) = \mathbb{Z}$

What if we take two copies of $S^2$ (or higher-dimensional spheres), and join them together not at a single point, but at a line. Is there a generalization of the wedge product that joins together the spaces not just at a point, but in a higher dimensional intersection?

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know what a colimit is in general?

Comment: No. How would category theory help us out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a space $A$ (here it would be the interval $I$ I guess if you want a line), and maps $f:A\to X$ and $g:A\to Y$ (so here $X=Y=S^2$), you can always glue $X$ and $Y$ along $A$, identifying the corresponding points in $X$ and $Y$.

In terms in category theory, this is the colimit of the diagram $X \leftarrow A \to Y$. You can see it more concretely if you want by taking a quotient of the disjoint union: $(X\coprod Y)/\sim$, where $\sim$ identifies $f(a)$ and $g(a)$ for any $a\in A$.

Comment: Such a colimit is known to many of its admirers as a [push-out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushout_(category_theory)).

Comment: And see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/645972/mayer-vietoris-type-sequence-for-pushouts for some information about homology of pushouts.